# Fixing bad timestamps on Skype 6.19

Tags: macos, skype, chat, timestamp

I was doing a bit of testing of a javascript app that had me changing my timezone all over the place. While that was happening, I got a couple of Skype messages that got assigned bad timestamps. Now the messages that think they are from the future are stuck at the bottom of my chatlog. How do I fix or remove these messages? I can't find the database file. I'm running Skype 6.19 on OSX 10.9.5

Comment: Just be patient and the problem will sort itself out.

Comment: I mean, yeah, but there's one from a week from now. It's really annoying, it gets in the way of work, and I'm sure I'm not the first person who has been bothered by this.